# Would it be worth adding a matchstick framework?

Tags: feature-request, questions

Do you think it would be worth adding a matchstick framework so all matchstick puzzles look nice and the same? I had this idea when trying to put into puzzle my matchstick idea but could not find a matchstick puzzle creator online!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think a matchstick framework would be implemented by Stack Exchange for PSE *(Puzzling Stack Exchange)*.

There are plenty of different types of puzzles, like [chess](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chess), [rubiks-cube](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rubiks-cube), [mazes](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mazes), etc. that would fall into your category of *"so all [insert tag name] puzzles look nice and the same"*, so it wouldn't make sense to only have one for the [matches](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/matches) tag.

*If* such a framework were to be implemented, it would likely be a convention to use it for the matchstick puzzles here, and that would introduce many limitations for creativity.